# Invalid or missing account ID GTM - container ID contains more than 6 characters

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have created a account in Google Tag Manager, and I am very new to it. My Container ID code is is GTM-XXXXXXX ( 7 characters ). 
I am getting an error about "Invalid or missing account ID"

I read it on different blogs that the error is due to 7 characters in the ID. But I did not understand properly if the error can be ignored or debugged.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you seeing this message? If it's in Google tag assistant, then you can ignore it

Comment: If you are 100% sure the ID is correct, the same error can occur when there is no published version of the container. Have you added something to your GTM and published it?

Answer (score 5):

According to Google this is a false error and it's going to be resolved in future.

See this [link](https://support.google.com/tagassistant/answer/3207128?hl=en) in **Invalid or missing account ID** section.

> NOTE: If your container ID (i.e. what’s referenced here as ‘account ID’) is of format GTM-XXXXXXX, where the portion after ‘GTM-’ is longer than 6 characters, you may see this error unnecessarily. This false error will be resolved in a future update. In the meantime, as long as your container ID follows the correct format as described below, you may ignore this error.

**You can ignore this error.**